# Special character in variable function bash

Tags: bash

I have the below call to a function which is accepting a variable "name" (file path from `find`)

I then want to use the file path to run some checks, however the find is picking up temp files containing a `$`.

So now when trying to use the first argument within the function the string is truncating at the `$`.

So

```
File=/root/fed/~$reader.txt
```

Is echoing as

```
/root/fed/eager.txt
```

Using '' is the popular answer put not sure how to apply here

Code is :

```
find / -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I name bash -c 'fnchash "name"' 

fnchash () {
    echo "$1"
}
```

Comment: Use single quotes in `fnchash` argument: `fnchash 'name'` to avoid `$` expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use single quotes to prevent Bash expanding the `$reader` in `name`.

Here's a demo just using `echo` for simplicity:

#### Before

```
bash-4.3$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I name bash -c 'echo "name"' 
./~.txt
```

#### After

```
bash-4.3$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I name bash -c "echo 'name'"
./~$reader.txt
```

You shouldn't need to alter `fnchash()`.

---

So, with:

```
fnchash () {
    echo "$1"
}
```

You should be able to call:

```
find / -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I name bash -c "fnchash 'name'"
```

And get the results you were looking for:

```
bash-4.3$ ls -laF
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 paj  staff   102  7 May 22:57 ./
drwxr-xr-x  55 paj  staff  1870  7 May 22:57 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 paj  staff     0  7 May 22:57 ~$reader.txt

bash-4.3$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I name bash -c "fnchash 'name'"
./~$reader.txt
```

Comment: I have tried single quotes around name but it just passes "name" to my function

Comment: Curious. I tested my answer using `GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0)
`.

Comment: Trying passing to a function like I'm doing above... You'll have to export the function using export -f functionname